# Remove/unset specific row from collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this eloquent query

```
 $result= Result::query()
            ->where('city_id', '=', $search_city)
            ->get();
        }
```

then inside loop

```
 foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    if(isset($row->user_id) && $row->user_id!=0)
                    {
                        $UserDetails = User::where('id',$row->user_id)->first();
                        if($UserDetails) 
                        {
                            if($UserDetails->type=='normal user')
                            {
                              // remove this specific row from result 
                            }
                
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

inside if condition if specific condition met i want to remove only that particular row from the result.

```
 return view('index', compact('result'));
```

Any solution Thanks

Comment: ``foreach($result as &$row) {  ... if() { ... if() { if() { unset($row); } } } }`` should work. But if you could explain what exactly you're trying to do then we can suggest some better solution. :)

Comment: I think you might be looking for the `forget($key)` method as described in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-forget

Comment: @OMiShah i Tried unset it is not working

Comment: @Techno this is for laravel 5 see tags

Comment: @francisco good point. If 5.0, this does not work, if 5.8 it does: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forget

Comment: The real question is, why don't you change the query so it isn't in the collection in the first place? take a look at `whereHas()`

Answer (score 0):

Just user `->filter()` to exclude an item on your original collection...

```
$results = $results->filter(function($result){
   $user = User::where('id',$result->user_id)->first();
   if (!$user) return true; // Include
   if ($user->type == 'normal user') return false; // Exclude
   return true; // Include
});
```

Comment: There are three conditions to return a boolean on on (due to the fact you are considering a $user may not exist), so you might need to change it if that should also exclude the returned $result.